# How to prove that a matrix is invertible $\iff$ invertible at right $\iff$ invertible at left?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ a $n\times n$ invertible at left. In fact, I just want to prove that it's invertible at right (the rest is obvious). All what I can say is that there is a $B$ s.t. $BA=I.$
To prova $AB=I$, I have problem. I have that $$AB=AB^2A=BA^2B,$$
but I can't conclude that it's $I$.

Comment: Is it a square matrix?

Comment: Yes it is. But an invertible matrix is necessarily square, isn't it ? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: You can continue if you would like to: $ = BA^2B^2A = BA AB BA$

Comment: @mathreadler: And so ?

Comment: First show that $B$ has a right inverse $C$. Then $A = ABC = C$ shows that they are equal.

Comment: I don't know, but it almost sounded like a sheep when i read it out loud.

Comment: @mathreadler: Not very respectful answer... but funny anyway :-)

Comment: @MathBeginner A non-zero $(1\times n)$ matrix is right invertible, but not left invertible. Implicitisation of hypothesis leads to explicitation of elementary questions.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, let $f_A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, x\mapsto Ax$ be the associated linear map. Since $BA = I$, we have $f_B\circ f_A = \operatorname{id}$, so $f_A$ is injective. But then $f_A$, as a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces of same dimension, is also surjective, hence bijective and so $A$ is invertible.

This is because $n = \operatorname{dim}(\ker f_A) + \operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im} f_A)$. Since $f_A$ is injective, $\operatorname{dim}(\ker f_A) = 0$, so $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{im} f_A) = n$, hence $f_A$ is surjective.

Comment: Something tells me this is using techniques not available to the OP yet.

Comment: I really like your answer (very powerful). But I can't use rank theorem. Sorry.

Comment: @MathBeginner Oh okay. Surely, somebody here comes up with a more elementary answer.

Comment: @MathBeginner there is no proof possible without using the condition of finite dimension in some way, counting dimension somehow. This is because the conclusion is false in infinite dimension, the easiest example being the left shift and right shift operators on countable sequences; in one order, the identity, in the other order, no.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences

Comment: @WillJagy I believe the OP specifically referred to the rank-nullity-theorem, not just to the finite dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

If you can try $B = \text{adj}(A)/\det(A)$ and show by brute force computation that $BA = I = AB$.

You would only need $B^jA_i = \delta_{ij}$ and $A^iB_j = \delta_{ij}$. (Superscript means row vector and subscript meaning column vector index, and $\delta_{ij}$ means indicator of $i = j$).

You only need to think about the relationship between the definitions of $\text{adj}$ and $\det$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

If additionally you know how transpose relates to inverse, I think you only need $B^jA_i = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure they can't use det, not sure about adj.

Comment: Both of these quantities have easy expression as terms of entries of the matrix. It would complicate the proof if we also had to show the determinant was non-zero. 

I think you may be right in any case that this isn't the spirit of the question but I can't think of a more elementary way right now.

Answer (score -1):

I'll assume that you have the result that $\det AB=\det A \det B$ and that the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

Suppose $BA=I$ and that $AB\neq I$. Then there exists $u$ such that $ABu=v$ for some $v\neq u$ and so $BABu=Bv$ hence $Bu=Bv$. This gives us $B(u-v)=0$ and so $u-v$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $0$.

It follows that $\det AB =(\det A) (\det B) = (\det A) 0 =0$. But $\det AB = \det I =1$ which is a contradiction.

It follows that if $BA=I$ then $AB=I$.

Comment: $ABu = v \Rightarrow AB(u-v) = 0$ Shouldn't it be $ABu = v \Rightarrow ABu - v = 0$

Comment: Sorry yep, I'll see if I can salvage the argument.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham Actually it becomes slightly simpler using the correct maths

Comment: You could actually get rid of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, since I don't think the OP can use it. Just go for $w = u - v \neq 0$ and $w \in ker(B)$

Comment: $\ker B$ being non-zero implying that $B$ is not invertible would take some work though.

Comment: What would mean $rank(B) \neq n$ what implies $rank(BA) \neq n$. Thus $BA \neq I$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42280/discussion-between-patrick-abraham-and-dan-rust).

Comment: I guess it really comes down to what tools are at the disposal of the OP. Various results that one would naturally need to prove while progressing through a course in linear algebra would make this question successively more simple compared to proving it from first principals.

Comment: using the determinant, the result is of course obvious ! So no, I can't use determinant.