# If $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ invertible at left then it's invertible at right.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

1) If it's invertible at left then it's invertible.

2) If it's invertible at right, then it's invertible.

---

I saw several proofs ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855237/how-to-prove-that-a-matrix-is-invertible-iff-invertible-at-right-iff-inver) and  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)), but they look much more complicated than what I did. So I'm I correct and if no, why ?

For 1) (because 2) is the same). **Way 1 :** We have that $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n, v\longmapsto Av$ is injective. By rank theorem it's also surjective. Therefore, there is $C\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ s.t. $AC=I$. But $$B=B(AC)=(BA)C=C,$$
and thus $A$ is invertible.

**Way 2 :** Let $B\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ s.t. $BA=I$. In particular, $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n; v\longmapsto Bv$ is surjective. By rank theorem it's also injective, and thus $$B(AB-I)=(BA)B-B=B-B=0\implies AB-I=0,$$
and thus $AB=I$, i.e. $A$ is invertible.

**Way 3 :**

Without using rank theorem. We have that $$BA=I.$$
We have $$B(AB-I)=0.$$
Since $B$ is invertible at right, it's surjective and thus full rank. Therefore, there are $P,Q\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ invertible s.t. $PBQ^{-1}=I$, i.e. $B=P^{-1}Q$.  Therefore $$B(AB-I)=P^{-1}Q(AB-I)=0\implies AB-I=0\implies AB=I.$$

Does it work ?

Comment: what you mean invertible at left?

Comment: An element $g$ of a group $G$ is invertible at left if there is $h\in G$ s.t. $hg=1$. @pointguard0

Comment: The other solutions try not to assume rank-nullity formula.

Comment: @Henri I would be careful using the word "group" there, as that carries with it an assumption that two-sided inverses already exist. "Monoid" would be better.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I made it in **way 3 :** does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct. 
The equivalence between invertible at left and invertible at right is a simple consequence of rank theorem.